# NullPointerException from ibatis when using FactoryBeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, ibatis

I revise some bean definition through a customized BeanFactoryPostProcessor
When the web application startup, it failed:

```
    @Component
public class RPCTimeoutPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RPCTimeoutPostProcessor.class);


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        overriderThriftTimeoutPolicy(beanFactory);
    }

    private void overriderThriftTimeoutPolicy(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        Map<String, ThriftClientProxy> map = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(ThriftClientProxy.class);
        Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    }
}
```

> [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'baseSystemApi': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'appConfigService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'appConfigService': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException:
>   nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>   Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException The
>   error may exist in com/xxx/dao/WmAppTextDao.java (best guess) The
>   error may involve com.xxx.dao.WmAppTextDao.getAll The error occurred
>   while executing a query Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)

Comment: Don't use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` for that use a `BeanPostProcessor` and check the type of bean. What you are doing here will result in very early bean instantiation and basically bypass all other Spring goodness.

Comment: ThriftClientProxy is a FactoryBean，it encapsulate the PRC client creation detail, which will invoke getTimeout() method when process a remote call，in **getObject** method it will return a dynamic proxy object for the real rpc call, using **BeanFactoryPostProcessor** I wanna change the default timeout, can I do the same thing by **BeanPostProcessor** ? @M.Deinum

Comment: Yes you can... But why so complex isn't there an easier way to configure the timeout? The fact that there is a `getTimeout` makes me wonder if there ins't simply a `setTimeout` which you can use to configure it by a simple property. What you are doing seems like overkill for setting a property.

Comment: Yeah，I can config the timeout by xml configuration file，but there are hundreds of  such config which we maintain for the production environment, in test environment I wanna override the timeout in the xml file and set all of them to 2seconds for example. Could you show me how to use BeanPostProcessor to do so? thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: Just as the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` but it operates on beans. Check the type and if it is one of those factory beans override the `setTimeOut` value. You can also do this with `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` but you need to lookup the `BeanDefinition` s instead of the actual beans.